# Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h) ?How to solve it>?

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode

```
int trap(vector<int>& height) {
    
    int n=height.size();
    vector<int> left;
    vector<int> right;
    
    left[0]=height[0];
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        left[i]=max(left[i-1],height[i]);
    }
    
    right[n-1]=height[n-1];
    for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
    {
        right[i]=max(right[i+1],height[i]);
    }
    
    int ans=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        ans+=min(left[i],right[i])-height[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
};
```

I did this code for trapping rainwater problem but it shows the above error idk how to solve ,I am stuck at this

Comment: `left[0]=height[0];` Change that to `left.at(0) = height.at(0);` and read the exception message when it shows up.  That explains everything you need to know as to why your program fails.

Answer (score 4):

With

```
vector<int> left;
vector<int> right;
```

you create two ***empty*** vectors. Any indexing into them will be *out of bounds* and lead to *undefined behavior*. Either set their size:

```
vector<int> left(n);
vector<int> right(n);
```

Or use `push_back` to dynamically add values.

Also note that `left[i-1]` will also lead to UB (Undefined Behavior) when `i == 0`. Which happens in the first iteration of the loop. You should probably start that loop with `int i = 1`.